# Why python script could not work in AWS ec2?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When my python code run in localhost,it work. But, it doesn't in AWS ec2?
My code is simple: send a https request with post method. It works in localhost, but it occurs problem in AWS ec2.

I change another https request, it works.So the network is ok.
The code and the received content are below:

````py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import random
import requests

url = 'https://www.haidilao.com/eportal/ui?moduleId=5&pageId=9c8cf76c4ca84fc686ca11aaa936f5c7&struts.portlet.action=/portlet/map-portlet!getMapDotDataByRegion.action&random='+str(random.random())

header = {
            'host':'www.haidilao.com',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
            }
data = {
            'queryContent': 'CA',
            'country':'6bf4038f63234217aecf93668a63f04b',
            'myLat':'',
            'myLng':''
        }
def test():
    data = parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
    req = requests.post(url,headers= header,data= data, verify= False)
    print(req.status_code)
    print(req.headers)
    print(req.text)

test()
```python


```html
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 60416
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 13:02:31 GMT
Server: nginx
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 14:05:06 GMT
ETag: "5d4d7d92-ec00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 46dd9ae2d97161deaefbdceeae5f57ac.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: SIN2-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: XNkaD2emKes3BpaY3ZVSGb1bxlnsHD1KZeHCZPXnOcspTaYXXjVzKA==

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>sorry，the channel has expired!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/eportal/uiFramework/css/tip.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="easysite-error">
<img src="/eportal/uiFramework/images/picNews/tip.png"  />
<font class="easysite-404"></font>
<font>sorry，the channel has expired!</font>
</div>
</body>
</html>
````

Comment: Could you please post the Python Script, would be way easier to help you with better context

Comment: Sorry for that. I have re-edited the question.